# Cursor does not move after inserting content the second time in CKEditor5 (Classic Editor) loaded in Android WebView

Tags: react-native, android-webview, ckeditor5

I am working with speech to text software and require to dynamically insert the text content into Classic Editor as and when user speaks. Following lines of code is written to insert content into the Editor

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
var viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView("< text to insert>");
var modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
writer.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
});
```

When the above lines of code to insert content is executed for the first time, text gets inserted and cursor moves to end of the content. For all further calls made to insert content the cursor does not move to the end of newly inserted content, instead it is stuck at the end of the first inserted text. Because of this every subsequent inserts happen in the reverse order

When text suggestion of the device Settings is turned off, it works fine. We cannot disable it by default and so need a solution where cursor moves to end of the inserted content

This works fine in iOS WebView and Android Chrome browser.